# For $z ∈ \mathbb C$ if the minimum value of $(|z-3 \sqrt{2}|+ |z-p \sqrt{2}i|) $ is $5 \sqrt{2}$ .Then what is the value of $p$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

For $z ∈ \mathbb C$ if the minimum value of $(|z-3 \sqrt{2}|$ + $|z-p \sqrt{2}i|) $ is $5 \sqrt{2}$. Then what is the value of $p$?

EDIT: Sorry the question on my paper had misprint. It is “+” and not “,” or “*”.

For any confusion , addition photo of question:
[image]

As I see it, the question means:
Where $|\;| =$ Mod $|z-3 \sqrt{2}|$ , $|z-p \sqrt{2}i|$

Q1: As per Mod, $z-3 \sqrt{2} = 5 \sqrt{2}$ or $-(5 \sqrt{2}$). Since $z$ belongs to set of complex number. $i=0$ here.

Now, which value should we choose? After this, we should assign a value to $z$ by substituting. Then, substitute this $z$ to the other part $|z-p \sqrt{2}i|$ and find $p$.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense when $z$ is not more restricted. Otherwise, when chosing $z=3\sqrt{2}$, the minimum is obviously $0$. Or is $z$ a constant, that just isn't known?

Comment: @Ingix Yes but they have given us a minimum value. Also , z belongs to complex numbers. It’s not told if its constant

Comment: Looking further, the whole questions is not really making sense to me. Obviously $p$ is a parameter that you need to determine (likely a range will be the reuslt). But what exactly $z$ is and if it can vary when considering the minimum I still don't see. Maybe somebody else here can see more.

Comment: @S.M.T $i^2 =-1$, so $i$ cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the triangle inequality: $$|z_1|+|z_2|\ge |z_1\pm z_2|$$
$$F=|z-3\sqrt{2}|+|z-p\sqrt{2} i|\ge |(z-3\sqrt{2})-(z-p\sqrt{2}i|=|3\sqrt{2}+p\sqrt{2}i|$$
The min valueof $F$ is $$\sqrt{18+2p^2}=5\sqrt{2} \implies p^2=16 \implies p=\pm 4$$

Edit: It is like in a triangle PAB  PA+PB$\ge$ AB, equality hold when P lies on AB.

Comment: The question had misprint. Pls check the Q now again.

Comment: How do we know if P lies on AB or not ?

Comment: Imagine triangle PAB and P falling down on AB. Then PA+PB=AB, when P is away from AB then PA+PB > AB.

Comment: We could use either of the 2 ways right in the question. Either > or <.

Comment: From where did u get $\sqrt{18+2p^2}$

Comment: $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: Ohk. Got it sir

Answer (score 1):

**The original question was edited. This answer is no longer relevant but may be of interest.**

A few points before I start:

- The modulus of a complex number is not the same as the absolute value of a real number. In the case of a complex number $z = a + bi, |z|^2 = a^2 + b^2$. The value $|z|$ is non-negative as it is meant to express a distance (this is crude terminology but I hope sufficient to convey the idea).
- From this follows another point. You state that if $|z-3\sqrt{2}| = 5\sqrt{2}$ then $i = 0$. My guess is that by $i = 0$ you meant that the imaginary part of $z-3\sqrt{2}$ is $0$, i.e. Im$(z-3\sqrt{2}) = 0$, but even so, given the formulation above, this cannot be assumed. We could have a non-zero imaginary part inside the modulus since the modulus never includes $i$ regardless of whether the number inside the modulus has a non-zero imaginary part or not.
- Stating $min(|z-3 \sqrt{2}|$ , $|z-p \sqrt{2}i|) = 5 \sqrt{2}$ (I assume by the * symbol you mean multiplication) means that either one of the moduli could be equal to $5\sqrt{2}$. From what you've given us there is no indication as to which one of these should be considered the minimum, or an explanation for why you chose it to be the first one.
- There is nothing to indicate what $p$ is. Is it a constant? If so, is it complex or real? Any restrictions on the values $p$ can take?

Since we have no restrictions on $z$ or $p$, the best we can do is come up with a general expression in terms of the real and imaginary values of z, and leave $p$ unspecified. Write $z = a + bi$ with $i^2 = -1$. Then

\begin{align}
|z - 3\sqrt{2}| = |(a-3\sqrt{2}) + bi| & = (a-3\sqrt{2})^2 + b^2 \\
& = a^2 +b^2 - 6a\sqrt{2} + 18 \\
& = |z| - 6a\sqrt{2} + 18
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
|z - p\sqrt{2}i| = |a + (b-p\sqrt{2})i| & = a^2 + (b-p\sqrt{2})^2 \\
& = a^2 +b^2 - 2bp\sqrt{2} + 2p^2 \\
& = |z| - 2bp\sqrt{2} + 2p^2,
\end{align}

and thus

$$
min(|z| - 6a\sqrt{2} + 18, |z| - 2bp\sqrt{2} + 2p^2) = 5\sqrt{2},
$$

but without further restrictions on $z$ and a more careful consideration of $p$ it is difficult to see where to go next.

Comment: Your title was wrong I have corrected it and answered again.